How to sample from all admissible populations of individuals from a given distribution?
Problem description
Below, the term "population" refers to a population of individuals in the ecological sense.
Suppose we are given a set $S \subset \mathcal{P}(T^N)$ of admissible populations and draw such admissible populations $s = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in S $ of individuals $x_i \in T$ in the following way:

First we draw a population size $n$ from a uniform distribution over $\{ 0,...,N \} $.
Then we draw $n$ individuals $x_i$ from a given random variable $X$ and add them to the set $s$.
Finally, we check if the population is admissible, which is the case if $s \in S$. If it is, we are done, if it is not, we repeat the procedure until we have found an admissible population.

I want to simulate the resulting sample in an efficient manner. However, the probability to obtain an admissible population in the first two steps is small, which is why using the outlined approach is not feasible in practice.
We may use that $\emptyset \in S$. I would like to consider the general case with any domain $T$, but in my specific application, $T \subseteq [1, \dots, m] \times [a, b]$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R$. In particular, the set $S$ is infinite and only implicitly defined via the admissibility check. The admissibility check behaves "somewhat continuous", meaning that if two populations "resemble" each other, it is likely that they are either both admissible or both inadmissible. The latter statement is meant to motivate the attempted solution below but not needed for my actual question.
Attempted solution
My take on solving this problem is to use a Metropolis-Hastings-type algorithm:

Start with some admissible population $s_0$.
With probability $0.5$, add a new individual $x$ drawn from $X$ to the population.

Otherwise, remove a random indivudal from the population (if the population is not empty).


Check if the new state is admissible. If it is, accept the step; otherwise keep the last admissible population.
Repeat this procedure very often.

Question
For this procedure to work, we need that the proposal distribution is balanced. That is, for the transition $s_j \rightarrow s_{j+1}$ it holds
$$P(s_{j+1} | s_j) = P(s_j | s_{j+1}).$$
However, when I delete an individual, $P(s_{j+1} | s_j) = \frac{1}{2 |s_j|} $, whereas adding an individual requires more information: $P(s_j | s_{j+1}) = 0.5 P(X = x)$ if $x$ is the new individual. Incorporaing this into the algorithm would lead to a dominance of small populations (and becomes difficult if $X$ has a continuous domain). Therefore, I believe I have a misconception.
I have the following questions:

Does the proposed algorithm yield the desired sample?
If yes, why? How could I prove / express this mathematically? || If no, how would I need to adjust the algorithm? (Again, a hint towards a proof would be awesome.)

Background
The populations may represent populations of organims that compete with one another for limited resources. My goal is to sample from all populations that we could find in nature (according to some model of competition). Depending on the species and the sizes of the individuals, they may occupy different niches, allowing many individuals to survive. However, if there are strong competitors in the same niche, some indivudals may die.

A simple way to balance the proposal distribution would be to at each step randomly sample one (or another fixed number) individual from the entire population and toggle its inclusion/exclusion.

@jblood94 What do you mean by "entire" population? $S$ or $s$? Or something else?

It would be a draw of $x$ from $X$. But on second thought, I don't think this will give the same stationary distribution as the sampling procedure described in the beginning of the question.

In order to get a satisfying answer, you should describe $S$. For a start, if $S$ is finite and knowable, the obvious solution would be to sample directly from $S$, with proper weighting.

@carlo I have added further details. $S$ is neither finite nor knowable; otherwise, the questions would not make a lot of sense I think.
